# Subdivision Mesh Color

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, theme

Editing vertices, faces and edges becomes difficult post subdivision. While I understand I can toggle off the subdivision during editing, it would be beneficial (to me) to be able to change the theme of the generated subdivision mesh as to decipher between it and the object's original mesh.

TL;DR: Is it possible to change the subdivision generated mesh color?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change *"wire"* or *"wire edit"* colors in the preferences:

[image]

To clarify, *"wire edit"* is the color for the editable part of the mesh.

For instance pink here (as this color does not or few overlap with others):

[image]

Comment: I never knew...  I often switch on wireframe display while modelling so I can see modifier effects.. but then, without this distinction, I have to double-take to see which mode I'm in. very helpful

Comment: To clarify: Is this same colour for all edges in that mode...rather than  a different colour for original vs modifier generated edge.