# How to display subdivision mesh to indicate edges generated by a modifier

Tags: mesh, theme

Is it possible to assign two different colours to a generated mesh by a modifier such as subdivision and that original belonging to an object?

Let's say I have this object:

[image]

If I turn on `On Cage` in Modifier section and turn off `Optimal Display` I can see the mesh I would have after applying the modifier

[image]

I thought changing the 3D Viewport Theme mainly `Wire` and `Wire Edit` would make it distinct between original and generated mesh. I found out about it in another post [Subdivision Mesh Color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193864/subdivision-mesh-color). However, it doesn't really work for me. Changing `Wire` has no effect at all whereas changing `Wire Edit` changes everything.

If it's not clear what I mean, here is what I would like to see, however without having to select the whole mesh

[image]